# vue-cli-service( version 2.6.10) build , getting HTML resonse from API call

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli

vue-cli-service (version 2.6.10) build, getting HTML response from index.html(**<noscript> We're sorry but your project doesn't work properly without javascript enable. Please enableit to continue</noscript>**) from API (axios API)

I can run my vue.js project locally without creating a build with the command **npm run dev** and it is perfectly working fine, like an API  getting called properly. For BE, I am using Python.
Once creating a build with the **npm run build:dev** command, the build is created inside **dist** folder, and I launched that build with the command **serve -s dist -l 9001**. My application is successfully launched with the login screen, After I entered the correct credential and clicked on the login button, the API got triggered, but in the response of the API, I got the response as HTML content, which is present in **index.html inside the public** folder as
 **We're sorry, but your project doesn't work properly without Javascript enabled. Please enable it to continue**

**I expect it will go to the BE server and get a proper response, but it should not.**

If I run my project without building it, like with the **npm run dev** command, then my application will work properly, communicate with BE, and get a proper response.

I attached some screen shots, to help understand the issue.(Screen shots regarding API calls , **vue.cofing.js, index.html, main.js** )
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]